# How can I import and query an XML file (in this case, a business process event log) into SQL Server Express?

Tags: sql-server, xml, events, event-log

To keep it short, I have this ".xes" (Extensible Event Stream) file, which is in fact an XML, and looks like this (this code only shows an example of an event - the file contains multiple events similar to this one):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<log xes.version="1.0" xes.features="nested-attributes" openxes.version="1.0RC7" xmlns="http://www.xes-standard.org/">
    <trace>
        <string key="concept:name" value="0"/>
        <event>
            <string key="org:resource" value="Call Centre Agent"/>
            <date key="time:timestamp" value="2006-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00"/>
            <string key="concept:name" value="check if sufficient information is available"/>
            <string key="lifecycle:transition" value="start"/>
        </event>
     </trace>
...
```

This file represents in fact a business process event log which contains the events of different activities of a process with timestamp and further information.

I need to extract the information from this data and prepare some SQL queries as well.

I am currently using a SQL Server 2014 Express database, and having trouble importing the data and querying it.

Comment: Could there be more than one event?

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of events, similar to this one. I only copied the one as an example.

Comment: You should really think about such things **before** you ask... I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a general approach to get a file's content into a variable:
This is a general approach to get a file's content into a variable:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
(SELECT *  FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\YourPath\XMLFile.xml',SINGLE_CLOB) AS x);
SELECT @xml;
```

As this is nested data (with unclear level of nesting...) this is my suggestion:

```
DECLARE @log XML=
'<log xmlns="http://www.xes-standard.org/" xes.version="1.0" xes.features="nested-attributes" openxes.version="1.0RC7">
  <trace>
    <string key="concept:name" value="0" />
    <event>
      <string key="org:resource" value="Call Centre Agent" />
      <date key="time:timestamp" value="2006-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00" />
      <string key="concept:name" value="check if sufficient information is available" />
      <string key="lifecycle:transition" value="start" />
    </event>
    <event>
      <string key="second-resouce" value="Call Centre Agent" />
      <date key="second:timestamp" value="2006-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00" />
      <string key="second:name" value="check if sufficient information is available" />
      <string key="second:transition" value="start" />
    </event>
  </trace>
</log>';

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.xes-standard.org/')
SELECT TraceNode.value('string[1]/@key','varchar(max)') AS Trace_String_Key
      ,TraceNode.value('string[1]/@value','int') AS Trace_String_Value
      ,EventNode.value('date[1]/@key','varchar(max)') AS Trace_Event_Date_Key
      ,EventNode.value('date[1]/@value','datetime') AS Trace_Event_Date_Value
      ,EventStringNode.value('@key','varchar(max)') AS Trace_Event_String_Key
      ,EventStringNode.value('@value','varchar(max)') AS Trace_Event_String_Value

FROM @log.nodes('/log/trace') AS a(TraceNode)
OUTER APPLY TraceNode.nodes('event') AS b(EventNode)
OUTER APPLY EventNode.nodes('string') AS c(EventStringNode)
```

> do you have any suggestions on how, and for what, could I query this
>   data? Some practical examples would be useful

Well, that's really up to you... If you ask such a question, you should know what you need it for :-)

One idea:

Create a relational table structure

- Table "Log" (Each log file and side data)
- Table "Event" (Child data to "Log")
- Table "EventData" (Child data to "Event")

You can use the query to retrieve your data to insert this into your tables...

Comment: I confirm, your approach does work. Thank you!
However, do you have any suggestions on how, and for what, could I query this data? Some practical examples would be useful.

Comment: @CCC Glad to read, that this works for you! Edited my answer... Please tick the acceptance check (below the vote counter) to confirm this.